# Access SQL Is a string-attribute part of another string in the same string-attribute of the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

In a Access Query, which is performed by the Microsoft JET 4.0 Driver,  i have to ask if a string-attribute part of another string in the same string-attribute of the same table?

[image: The table]

Example: In the table above, there is the string-attribute 'name' and i want to have a query that gives me all [Name]-words, that are contained in another [Name]-word (in this example i want to get at least 'Attack' but there should be more words than just this).

I've already tried s.th. like this:

```
SELECT [Name] 
FROM [t_object]
WHERE '%'+[Name]+'%' IN (SELECT [Name] FROM [t_object])
```

I was thinking about, if it is possible to use the InStr-Function in Combination with LIKE but i do not know how.

How can i find all words in the attribute [Name], that are already contained in another word?

Comment: For Access, you need to use `*` as a wildcard, not `%` as in regular sql.

Answer (score 2):

In Access the wildcard char that denotes any number of chars is `'*'` and not `'%'`.
You can use the `LIKE` operator like this:

```
SELECT [Name] 
FROM [t_object]
WHERE [Name] LIKE '*Attack*';
```

which will give all the values of column that contain `'Attack'`.
 
If you want all the rows of `[Name]` where this value is contained in another `[Name]`, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.[Name] 
FROM [t_object] AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [t_object] 
  WHERE [Name] <> t.[Name] AND 
  [Name] LIKE '*' + t.[Name] + '*'  
)
```

or with a join to get both values:

```
SELECT t.[Name] AS contained, tt.[Name] AS container 
FROM [t_object] AS t INNER JOIN [t_object] AS tt
ON t.[Name] <> tt.[Name] AND tt.[Name] LIKE '*' + t.[Name] + '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this would require some extra work but i can give you a head start...
At first i can't see how you can do it in one shot..maybe other contributors have a better idea but this what i tried.
At first you need to extract all the words to an extra table..lets call it NameWords
The table should have this simple structure
ID --> AutoNumber
NameWord --> ShortText
Here you will put all the words you have in Name
1 Attack
2 Pattern
The you will perform a Left Join between your current table and this table using InStr or Like and you will get all the records that have a match against NameWords  . (along with the ones that don't have)
I did a little test on this and it returned everything as expected using this

```
SELECT [t_object].*,NameWords.NameWord 
FROM [t_object] LEFT JOIN NameWordsON Instr(t_object.Name,NameWords.NameWord );
```